# Test the convergence of the series $\sum [(n^3+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}- n]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Test the convergence of the series $\sum [(n^3+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}- n]$

I have no idea which test to use here because of this complicated expression.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

$$(n^3+1)^{\frac13}-n = \frac{1}{(n^3+1)^{\frac23}+(n^3+1)^{\frac13}n+n^2} \le \frac1{3n^2}$$

Comment: To be slightly more clear: this comes from the factorization $1=(n^3+1)-n^3=a^3-n^3 = (a-n)(a^2+na+n^2)$, where $a=\sqrt[3]{n^3+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

We have, for $n\geq 1,$$$
n\leq (n^3+1)^{1/3} = n\left(1+\frac{1}{n^3}\right)^{1/3} \leq 
n\left(1+\frac{1}{3n^3}\right)
$$
the last inequality being [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Bernoulli%27s_inequality).

Therefore,
$$
0 \leq (n^3+1)^{1/3} - n \leq \frac{1}{3n^2}
$$
allowing you to conclude by comparison with the series $\sum_n \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$n^{th}$ term of the series is

= $ (n^3+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}- n$

= $ n(1+\frac{1}{n^3})^{\frac{1}{3}}- n$

= $ n(1+\frac{1}{3n^3} + other terms)- n$ . . . . . .  . .(other terms goes to 0 as n approaches $\infty$)

= $ \frac{1}{3n^2}$ + other terms

Now as $n\to\infty$ ,our $n^{th}$ term can be shown with following inequality

= $ \frac{1}{3n^2}$+other terms$ \le \frac{1}{n^2} < \frac{1}{n}$

Since $n^{th}$ term of series is less than $\frac{1}{n}$, the series is convergent